# msbuild no longer working after switching project from svn to git

Tags: msbuild

I have a project that was recently switched from svn to git. It was also just upgraded to VS2012, but the .NET/MVC versions remain the same. I can still build it fine on my local machine, but now the machine I use for CI is giving me the following error:

```
LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ActiveReports3, Version=5.2.1178.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777XXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.'
```

The job is being fired off by jenkins and is correctly pulling the right branch down from git, and I have verified that activereports3.dll is in the project directory, with full permissions. Any other ideas as to what might be causing this? Haven't turned up any other ideas on Google. Thanks!

Comment: Your project was a VS2010 project ? Framework 3.5 ?

Comment: It was 2008 and 3.5 yes

Comment: I don't think this has anything do with switching SCM, its all about upgrading your project. Anyway i think ActiveReports3 1178.2 is .net 2 not 3?

Comment: I also think we have to upgrade activereports, just haven't had the time to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the .csproj (from before the conversion and then after the conversion) in notepad (or other text editor) and see if the hintpath for the ActiveReports3 was altered.  Perhaps to a "hard path" like "C:\Program Files\ActiveReports\ActiveReports3.dll" or similar.

Comment: Good guess, both references are the same though.